# SP2007 Workflow: Lookup XXXX property for XXX by Title?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

Does anybody know if there is a way to use the `Look site user property` but search by the user's title instead of their NTLogin/Username?

Example:
`Lookup JobTitle property for John Smith, store in Variable: JobTitle`

I am received the following error: `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: User not found.`

Is there a different way I can format this request that still allows me to use the user's title instead of their username?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by using a "Person or Group" column. I used the workflow to update the "Person or Group" column with the user's title, and then used the "Person or Group" column to perform the property lookup in the workflow.